# Как сделать что-бы при нажатии на кнопку появлялось дополнительный поля ввода

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, форма, ввод

Как сделать так что-бы при нажатие на кнопку появлялись дополнительные поля ввода.Суть задания.Есть три основных поля ввода это 1-имя,2-номер,3-марка.
У автомобиля есть характеристики которые тоже надо ввести 1-модель,2-цвет,3-номер.Если автомобилей несколько то по нажатию кнопки должны появляться ещё поле ввода марки и три поля модель,цвет,номер.Если обычный ввод,я могу реализовать это на php, но как сделать такой понять не могу. Подскажите нубу,срочно надо.

Comment: Например. Вы можете обернуть вашу форму ввода в `div`. 
А потом клонировать его с помощью JS. 
Получите множество полей - например `carName[]` . Это будет `$_POST` массив. Их переберете `foreach` и дальше делайтe с ними что хотите.

Для JS код примерно такой - 
    `$('#cloneBtn').click(function(){
        $('.div').append( $('#carName').eq(0).clone().val('') );
        return false;
    });`

Comment: да, конечно! Оборачивать в div надо сами поля, а не форму. Как написал ниже @Sergey Kotkov

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно выделить вашу форму с автомобилем в отдельный div

```
<div class="auto">
    <input name="name"/>
    <input name="color"/>
</div>
```

и при необходимости копировать для каждого нового автомобиля.
Так же, как вариант можно вынести html с формой для автомобилей и вставлять его в форму каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку. Наверно этот вариант даже правильнее.
Данные об автомобилях лучше хранить в каком-нибудь универсальном формате, например json